# Add AW Blog link to Magento top menu

Tags: magento, menu, blogs

Using the Magento 1.4 blog plug-in "AW Blog", how is it possible to get the "News" link it creates to appear in Magento's top menu (as opposed to the top links menu which it does by default)?

Answer (score 1):

After changing AW Blog 'Route to Blog' configuration from 'news' to 'blog', add this to top.phtml :

```
  <div class="nav-container">       
    <ul id="nav">
    <?php echo $_menu ?>
      <li><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('blog')?>"><?php echo $this->__('Blog') ?></a></li>
    </ul>
```

Probably no the most elegant solution as I didn't want Blog at the end of the menu, so if there's a better solution out there...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it but this extension seems to allow adding an arbitrary link to the menu.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/extension/657/navigation-bar-administrator